# Link up XML documents with Foreign key

Tags: xml

I have created XML files from my database table, but I am not able to link up the documents with foreign keys as in the database. It might be a simple one but I am new to this and want to get the idea for it.

The XML files from first table

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Students>
    <Student>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>Student1</Name>
        <Roll>21</Roll>
    </Student>
...
</Student>
```

And the second XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PhoneNumbers>
    <PhoneNumber>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <StudentID>ISA</StudentID>
        <Number>12345</Number>
    </PhoneNumber>
...
</PhoneNumbers>
```

I need to link up the `studentID` of second xml with the `ID` of the first xml.

I suppose to use different xml files as I have got a huge number of data in the database. Is is all ok with it?

Comment: I don't understand how you want to *link* two XML files, based on some values contained in them...... XML files cannot be *linked* per se..... there's no infrastructure in place to *link* XML files....